# Postgresql + Hibernate 6 + Store Function cannot call

Tags: postgresql, hibernate-6.x

I create a very simple stored function like this

```
            CREATE
            OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function(id varchar, OUT res_id varchar, OUT res_code int)
            language plpgsql as
            $$
            begin
            -- body
                res_id := id;
                res_code := 5;
                return;
            end; $$
```

I try to call function by code from the article: https://vladmihalcea.com/best-way-call-stored-procedure-jpa-hibernate/

There is the calling code

```
    public TestFunctionResult callTestFunction(String id) {
        StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
                .createStoredProcedureQuery("test_function")
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter("id", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter("res_id", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter("res_code", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
                .setParameter("id", id);
        TestFunctionResult testFunctionResult = new TestFunctionResult();
        try {
            query.execute();
            testFunctionResult.setId((String)query.getOutputParameterValue("res_id"));
            testFunctionResult.setCode((Integer) query.getOutputParameterValue("res_code"));
        } finally {
            query.unwrap(ProcedureOutputs.class).release();
        }
        return testFunctionResult;
    }
```

All is worked fine with hibernate 5, but with hibernate 6 I catch the following error

```
ERROR: test_function(character varying) is not a procedure
 Hint: To call a function, use SELECT.
 Position: 6
```

I have created the two projects for hibernate 5 and hibernate 6. I have pushed them to github. There are the following projects: https://github.com/demid1984/stackoverflow.

P.S. I'm really hope there is a way to use the approach from the article for calling stored function.

Can anybody help me with this problem, please?

Comment: It would probably be worth putting the fragment of code you use to call that function into your question

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

There are various factors at play. The main problem is that you're trying to call a PostgreSQL function as if it was a procedure, but they are now different things.

### Longer answer

Various RDBMS have different terminology for "stored procedures" or "functions".

Until PostgreSQL 11, [PostgreSQL didn't have "procedures", just "functions"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2357/2129). It now [has both](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xproc.html), in particular:

> - Procedures are defined with the `CREATE PROCEDURE` command, not `CREATE FUNCTION`.
> - Procedures do not return a function value; hence `CREATE PROCEDURE` lacks a `RETURNS` clause. However, procedures can instead return data
>   to their callers via output parameters.
> - While a function is called as part of a query or DML command, a procedure is called in isolation using the `CALL` command.

More specifically, regarding your use case, you won't be able to use an actual "procedure", but you'll need to keep using a "function", since you want to return some values.

The addition of actual procedures has required some changes in both the JDBC driver (which has a [specific section of documentation on this topic](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/callproc/) and Hibernate.

Part of the problem is that the [JDBC driver can't easily guess which one needs to be used](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1413).

Hibernate 5 didn't have support for actual PostgreSQL procedures as far as I know.

The PostgreSQL dialect in Hibernate 6. The [`PostgreSQLCallableStatementSupport` JavaDoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/procedure/internal/PostgreSQLCallableStatementSupport.html) says this:

> Until version 11, stored procedures weren't supported in PostgreSQL,
> but the JDBC driver allowed calling functions with the JDBC call
> syntax by translating to select statements. Unfortunately, the JDBC
> driver can't differentiate between functions and stored procedures and
> calling functions is not allowed with the PostgreSQL 11+ native 'call
> xxx' syntax. This is why the driver introduced a config property
> 'escapeSyntaxCallMode' that has the options 'callIfNoReturn', 'call'
> and 'select' (default).
>
> Since Hibernate knows if it is being asked to invoke a function or
> real procedure, the following implementation tries to be agnostic of
> the driver setting by using the native syntax where possible.
>
> [...]
>
> Even though the rendered callable is different, the behavior should
> match that of previous Hibernate versions, yet this should work
> regardless of the configured 'escapeSyntaxCallMode'.

Visibly, it's not working quite as transparently as you would expect in your use case.

You have various options to solve this:

I'm not familiar with Hibernate's `StoredProcedureQuery` implementation, but it's possible it could also be cast to a `ProcedureCall`, in which case you could try to call `markAsFunctionCall` explicitly yourself.

However, the easiest might just be to call your function with a native query using `SELECT`. I haven't tried, but it should look roughly like this:

```java
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM test_function(:id)");
q.setParameter("id", id);
Object[] row = (Object[]) q.getSingleResult();
```

(Named parameters might not be compatible with other JPA implementations.)

I haven't tried either, but you might also be able to map it directly to your type if you name the columns according to the fields you expect (e.g. `t(id,code)`):

```java
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
              "SELECT * FROM test_function(:id) t(id,code)",
              TestFunctionResult.class);
q.setParameter("id", id);
TestFunctionResult testFunctionResult = (TestFunctionResult) q.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Right now I have found a workaround - set the hibernate dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect

Comment: Which one were you using?

Comment: I have added PostgreSQL10Dialect in project with hibernate 6.

Comment: I meant, which one were you using before?

Comment: I used the default dialect. I think there is org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

Comment: Any updates here ?
I have the same problem after migration to spring boot 3.x

Comment: @AmirChoubani If you use the latest dialect available, it should work

Comment: i am using this one:
`org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`
I still get the same error.

Comment: old code (with spring boot 2.7 and hibernate 5):
```
        @Procedure(value = "f_function_name")
 @Modifying
 int my_method(@Param("param1") long param1,
                                   @Param("param2") LocalDate param2);
```
I tried this new way:
```
      @Query(value = "select * from f_function_name(:param1, :param2)", nativeQuery = true)
 int optimizeManquantsMagasinsPCA(@Param("param1") long param1,
                                   @Param("param2") LocalDate param2);
```
I don't know if is the correct one or not ?