# Cannot call Postgresql Function using SpringBoot 3.2.0 (using Hibernate 6)

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-6.x

I am facing an issue after migrating from Spring Boot 2.5 to 3.2.0 where I am not able to call Postgresql Function using entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery() .

My Postgre Function returns a table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION abc.my_func(
   v_response bigint)
    RETURNS TABLE(variableA bigint, variableB text, variableC bigint, phone character varying)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ..........
```

The function calling code:

```
 StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
                .createStoredProcedureQuery("abc.my_func", ResultTable.class)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Long.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .setParameter(1, Long.valueOf(myvariable));
try{
    query.getResultList().forEach(i->results.add((ResultTable)i));
}
```

This above code is working in SpringBoot 2.5 using Hibernate 5 but in Hibernate 6 I am getting below error,

```
ERROR: abc.my_func(bigint) is not a procedure
 Hint: To call a function, use SELECT.
 Position: 6
```

After some scrolling through the internet, I came across the below post where user is facing the same issue but in Spring boot 3.1.2, and as a workaround he is setting hibernate dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect which resolves the issue.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76927479/postgresql-hibernate-6-store-function-cannot-call](https://stackoverflow.com)
But in my case, in SB 3.2 org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect has been depricated and I am getting ClassNotFoundException if I set it.
I even tried using entityManager.createNativeQuery and @Query and tried to directly run the query and store the result in ResultTable. But I am getting exceptions with Mapping the result to my Entity class.

Excepting using @Query

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to class com.sample.dto.ResultTable (org.postgresql.util.PGobject and com.sample.dto.ResultTable are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Exception using createNativeQuery (variableA is the Id for the entity class ResultTable )

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to find column position by name: variableA [The column name variableA was not found in this ResultSet.] [n/a]
```

I even tried @  SqlResultSetMapping but still error

```
org.hibernate.query.results.MissingSqlSelectionException: ResultSet mapping specified selected-alias `variableA` which was not part of the ResultSet
```

Can someone please help who has already implemented this, I am totally stuck on this unable to find any reference.
I am using postgresql 12 database provided by Google Cloud SQL and need to find a soln for version 12 only, cant upgrade SQL version.

Comment: 1) Function != stored procedure, so it is not surprising that `createStoredProcedureQuery` fails. 2) This *The column name variableA was not found` ...* raises the possibility that  this is name case issue. What happens if you run the function in say [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html), does the output table have the column name case preserved?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver no it does not actually. It gives 'my_func record' as column name and gives the data like (123, "abc", .....)

Comment: You need to do `select * from my_func();`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you !!!! I was able to resolve this issue by calling the function using 
`createNativeQuery("select * from my_func()", ResultTable.class) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Adrian I was able to resolve this issue by calling the function using,

```
Query query=em.createNativeQuery("select * from my_func(:resp)", ResultTable.class).setParameter("resp", Long.valueOf(myvariable));
List<ResultTable> res =query.getResultList();
```